# How to access Global variables from Fortran functions

Tags: fortran

Specifically, I am trying to emulate [the solution to Project Euler 31](https://projecteuler.net/overview=031) in Fortran. In order to do this, I need to read from an array of coins. And as the function is recursive, since the function will be called loads of times, I don't want to have to pass the list in as an argument each time, because if I have loads of copies of the list the code would have loads of memory overhead. Furthermore, in previous problems, like a function to simplify a fraction, I needed to pass through a very large list. So my question is: In Fortran, How do you access variables defined in the main program from a function. Is it even achievable, and if not, how much would intent(in) help in mitigating any memory duplication?

If necessary:

```
RECURSIVE FUNCTION NWAYS(AMOUNT,CUR_COIN,) RESULT(RES)
IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER            :: AMOUNT, CUR_COIN, RES, COINS !Coins is a list defined in the main program
RES = 0
IF (CUR_COIN<=1) THEN
  RES = 1
  RETURN
END IF

DO WHILE(AMOUNT>=0)
  RES = RES + NWAYS(AMOUNT,CUR_COIN-1)
  AMOUNT = AMOUNT-COINS(CUR_COIN)
END DO

RETURN

END FUNCTION NWAYS
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to define the variable in a module and USE the module in the function. So you would have something like:

```
module var_mod
integer, allocatable :: coins(:)
end module var_mod

program euler
use var_mod
...
allocate (coins(ncoins))
...
recursive function nways (...)
use var_mod
...
```

Now in nways, array coins is visible and you don't have to pass it each time. I made coins allocatable so that you can allocate it to the desired size in the main program.

Comment: Thank you for the response. However, I have a follow on question. Say that you have to generate the list in the module, how would you do that. My compiler says that I can't use any executable statements in a module so how would I generate, say, a large list of prime numbers

Comment: @L5RK - modules can contain subs and functions _after_ the [**`contains`**](http://annefou.github.io/Fortran/modules/modules.html#modules) statement.

Comment: Ok. thank you, this has been very helpful. One last question, if that's ok: Is there no way to access variables generated in the main body of the code directly, for things like IO and whatnot. Is calling predefined modules the only way?

Comment: If the main program has contained procedures, then variables in the main program are visible in the internal procedures (unless blocked by a declaration of the same name). For example:
`program main
integer myvar
...
contains
subroutine sub
print *, myvar
end subroutine sub
end program main`